# Has anyone successfully booted to a local VM from a .VMDK downloaded from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vmware-workstation, bitnami

Exporting a custom image to Cloud Storage I did this, then downloaded the .VMDK file one large 30gb file.

I have VMware workstation Pro 15.5 I am new to this whole VM thing. I managed to make an image of my GCP webserver instance and then saved it in my bucket to a .VMDK file and downloaded it.

[image: The place it stalls the VM on startup]

I get so far as "Clock Source: Switched clocksource to tsc" Then it stalls the Virtual Machine.

It is a Bitnami stack of Debian 10, wordpress pro, ngnix and lets encrypt.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is the scoop instead of adding a SCSI HDD, you have to add the .VMDK as an IDE HDD.

It booted to linux login
[image: BOOT!]